# A confusing word "education" :)

Tags: prepositions, articles

What's the best way to express?

> All translations are checked and corrected by the American teacher
>   with the education in literature

or

> All translations are checked and corrected by the American teacher
>   with the degree in literature

I'm not sure about articles as well))))
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ['degree'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/degree) as it emphasizes a certain mastery:

> a title conferred on students by a college, university, or professional school on completion of a program of study

Furthermore, you should use 'a'/'an' instead of 'the':

> All translations are checked and corrected by an American teacher with a degree in literature.

'the American teacher' would imply that the person reading/hearing the sentence would already know which teacher is meant (e.g. when there is only one American teacher.)